# Low Reorder not overriding the default filter settings

Tags: low-reorder

I'm using a Low Reorder set with a limited Statuses list in the filter settings, e.g.

[image: Current and Current-Store by default]

but there is one page that I would like to use different statuses.

```
{exp:low_reorder:entries status="Current-Store|Store"}
```

Unfortunately, the status parameter is not overriding the default filter settings, despite not using the `force_set_params` parameter at all.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a Low Reorder set, the entries get saved according to the set's filters. That means the entries in that set are limited to the entries that match the given filters.

If you want to override any of the parameters set in the Set's filter in the Entries tag, those filters will therefore be applied *on top of* the Set's entries. If you define a different status than the one given in the set, that won't match any of the Set's entries, because they didn't have that status in the first place.

So, if you give additional parameters, they will be applied *after* the set's filters (parameters) are applied; basically you're just *excluding* other entries from the Set, which means the order of the entries can still be applied.

If you want to define *different* parameters, new entries would apply, and Low Reorder has no way of knowing in which order those new entries should be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes perfect sense.  I've updated the filter settings to include everything, but restricted them further as necessary on all respective templates.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that this approach works...

```
{exp:low_reorder:entries rules:status="matches[Open|Drafts]"}
```